# Ubuntu WSL "docker run X" not possible despite service running

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There is a problem I have been trying to figure out the cause so that I can fix it.

Context: Windows 10 OS with WSL2 enabled + Ubuntu on Windows `v2004.2022.1.0` installed.
I have installed docker by these three packages; `docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`. I then used custom overrides in `daemon.json`, so that I can access it easily from Windows (browser/IDE);

```
karel:~$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "hosts": [
    "unix:///mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock"
  ],
  "registry-mirrors": [
    "company url"
  ]
}
```

I also have created a group, `docker`, added my user to it and let that group interact with the said socket (see further below). When I started the service, docker runs fine. This is given from `/var/log/docker.log`

```
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.577852700+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio throttle.write_iops_device"
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.578513800+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.732167500+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.807372700+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.882856700+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=a89b842 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.17
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.883136500+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
time="2022-08-30T12:06:12.912593800+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock"
```

When I want to attest if I can spin a container, I used docker's `hello-world`. This fails with a message that tells me the daemon is not running, despite the service is running.

```
karel:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker/sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.

karel:~$ service docker status
 * Docker is running
```

I have a feeling that there's an access mismatch but I don't have an idea how to troubleshoot access management than checking by `stat` or `ls -l`. I have used `stat` on the daemon;

```
karel:~$ stat /mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock
  File: /mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 8           Links: 1
Access: (0660/srw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (36257/  docker)
Access: 2022-08-30 12:06:12.245909900 +0200
Modify: 2022-08-30 12:06:12.245909900 +0200
Change: 2022-08-30 12:06:12.245909900 +0200
 Birth: -
```

The group `docker` is a custom group (see above) I've made to add users to it. At this moment, I am the only member of it;

```
karel:~$ getent group docker
docker:x:36257:karel
```

What did I miss? Or am missing? What are the steps I can do to tackle down this problem; that I can spin a docker container?

Comment: What if you back out the `daemon.json` changes?  That's the only thing you have that would be a delta from the stock Docker install, right?  On a Docker Desktop installation, I see quite a few shared sockets, not just the one, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.  Have you considered Docker Desktop?  It's free for individuals or small organization use, and, if your employer is larger, still almost certainly cheaper than what your employer is paying you to come up with these workarounds ;-).

Comment: It seems you are trying to install docker inside wsl with apt-get. Docker desktop for windows integrates pretty well with ubuntu wsl.